# Вставить символ " * " до и после определенного символа или нескольких символов

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Нужно написать функцию на Javascript которая бы вставляла символ * до и после указанного символа. Например:

```
print star(“abcabcbbahebbb”, “bb”);
Output: abcab*bb*ahe*bb*b

print star(“abcdhklmalh”, “h”);
Output: abcd*h*klmal*h*
```

Моя функция преобразует строку в массив и я хочу вставить символ при помощи `slice` но скрипт просто зависает. Почему так происходит и что делать (нельзя использовать replace, indexOf):

```
function star(string, token)
{
    var res = string.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i <= res.length-1; i++)
    {
        if(res[i] === token){
             res.splice(res[i-1],0,"*"); //здесь хочу вставить символ *
        }
    }
    console.log(res);
}
star("aaadaaa", "d");
```

Comment: не знаю как на счет зависает, но у вас в `res[i]` всегда один символ будет, а в `token` от 1 и выше.... и `res[i] === token` будет работать только когда ищите один символ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я прохожу по массиву и сравниваю каждый элемент массива с token, если они равны я хочу сделать res.splice(), и вставить * до этого элемента, но так не работает.

Comment: знаю, я просто напоминаю, в чем как минимум будет трабл.... а тут, кмк, нужно новую строку формировать, конкатинируя символы, а не делать splice.......вставить символ в массив можно только сместив остальные символы на шаг вправо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно написать функцию на Javascript которая бы вставляла символ...

Можно не раскладывать строку в массив в теле функции и не ходить по нему в цикле, а воспользоваться функциями замены в js:

```js
function star(string, token) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp(token, 'g'), '*'+token+'*');
}

console.log(star('abcabcbbahebbb', 'bb'));
console.log(star('abcdhklmalh', 'h'));
```

Либо - разбить строку на подстроки по разделителю `token` и сложить обратно с другим разделителем `*token*`:

```js
function star(string, token) {
  return string.split(token).join('*'+token+'*');
}

console.log(star('abcabcbbahebbb', 'bb'));
console.log(star('abcdhklmalh', 'h'));
```

Comment: спасибо, элегантно, но нужно без replace, в этом то и дело )

Comment: Дополнил ответ вариантом с split/join

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в том, что вы вставляете звездочку перед искомым, после этого длина массива увеличивается, происходит инкремент итератора, однако искомый символ сдвинут на единицу из-за вставленной звездочки, и текущий символ опять тот же самый, поэтому алгоритм уходит в бесконечный цикл. А еще не вижу ни одной причины писать `i <= res.length - 1` вместо `i < res.length`.

Т.е. вам как минимум нужно увеличивать **i** еще на 1 после того, как вы вставили звездочку

Comment: + условие if(res[i] === token){ никогда не выполнится если токен больше 2х символов

Comment: Да, и по представленному выше образцу звездочку нужно вставлять еще и после символа

Comment: @Alexander Да, согласен, бесконечный цикл пропал, но звездочку не вставляет.

Comment: почему splice не вставляет звездочку?

Comment: Не уверен, но вставлять ее нужно как минимум не по **i-1**, а по **i**

Comment: @Alexander ну я и так и так пробовал ) не хочет, просто возвращает массив без изменений